# use hand gesture instruction to turn on settings

Tags: android

I don't know what should be known or which is used to display instructions to `turn on permissions` in android.

In my app, I am requesting user permission and I want to show some demo like the following image,

[image: permission]

I googled a lot. I didn't see any related links. How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Please guide me.Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some 3rd party libraries from Github to get a similar effect, such as:

- https://github.com/wooplr/Spotlight
- https://github.com/TakuSemba/Spotlight

Comment: Thanks!But I don't want  to use 3rd party libraries

Comment: You can look at each lib's source code and learn how they implement this feature, then implement it yourself based on your needs.